# ACPI Volume Control (not brightness)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, acpi, root-filesystem

For some reason, upon upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, my volume and brightness media controls are no longer registering as XF86 keys. I created an acpi event and action script for my screen brightness in `/etc/acpi` wherein I modify the number in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, which works fine.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to track down where in `/sys/class` I can modify volume. Searching online hasn't yielded any results - anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try searching for how to increase and decrease volume on pulseaudio with relative values on the command line. I've found it before...

Comment: As far as I am aware, no driver (not even laptop specific ones) has volume control via ACPI. That's done via the audio hardware, i.e. ALSA, or Pulseaudio on top of it.